# JPA @Column definition does not apply to read operations?

Tags: java, jpa

Given I have entity `Car` with column `model` which doesn't accept `NULL`s

```
@Table(name = "CAR")
@Entity
public class Car extends AbstractEntity<Long> {

    @Column(name = "MODEL", nullable = false)
    private final String model;

}
```

When I prepare database schema, insert data (including `NULL`s in `MODEL` column) manually and start up application, it doesn't fail to start.

Why is that?

Do conditions specified in `@Column` annotation only apply for insert/update operations, not for read operations?

Comment: Schema definition only. Use javax.validation if you want to prevent INSERTs/UPDATEs

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can read null values with `nullable = false`. But when you try to save or update an entity with `model = null`, the `JPA` lever error will be thrown.

Check out the [specification for nullable](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#nullable--).

This JPA constraints just prohibit non-valid data from being written to the database, in order not to call it for no reason (by the way, you should have the same constraints in your database as you have in JPA).

These constraints have nothing to do with data that is already there. So that's why your application doesn't fail to start.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181632/why-should-i-specify-column-nullable-false) answer for better explanation.

Comment: What do you mean by JPA level constraint? Application needs to use JPA level for reading as well

Comment: @PatrikMihalčin I mean it just prohibits non-valid data from being written to database (by the way, you should have the same constraints in the database)

Comment: @htshame Maybe, you can rework your answer to increase clarity. Second, please use/insert a reference on the behaviour of `nullable` via the official JPA specification document (section or page number).