# In JPA, what does setting a column's nullable to false actually do?

Tags: java, jpa

In JPA, if a column isn't nullable, it must have a default value. So if I say

```
@Column(nullable=false)
Boolean isExpired;
```

Would it `default` to `true` or `false`? What if it's an `Integer` or a `Long` or a `String`? Is there any way to specify this?

Comment: Note that if your column is non-null, you should generally use the primitive instead of the wrapper.

Comment: For your reference  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181632/why-should-i-specify-column-nullable-false https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-notnull-vs-nullable#:~:text=The%20%40Column(nullable%20%3D%20false)%20Annotation&text=It's%20used%20mainly%20in%20the,to%20the%20particular%20database%20column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Column(nullable=false)` simply means that you should always supply value to that field when inserting or updating. If you want to specify a default value you can always add this:

```
 @Column(columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
```

But as per your question, if you will not define a specific value for that field (through columnDefinition), it will still be `null` and will prompt an error during DB insert or update if it's null.

Comment: When using JPA, it would be better to use a Java initialization `expired = false`.

Comment: As far as I can see, the JPA @Column annotation doesn't have an expired attribute.